# How to run java In background

Tags: java, android, button, background

How to run this in background , I mean even I move to other app or go to home screen of my android or close the screen , the button will still clicking itself
please help me

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
button1.performClick();
}
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Things to know**

I will try to elaborate as much as I can in a layman terms so that you have a better grasp the Idea of **Threads and async tasks**

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
     //business logic
   }
}, 5000);
```

1. is an **`Blocking`** method, which runs on the UI thread (I am supposing you are new to programming/android)[please read about **Threads** to understand what I am saying in deapth],
2. which means, in short, your application is executing some logic on the thread ("A worker" which is responsible for the rendering the UI on-screen),
3. By using **Threads** you can achieve efficiency in your application by dividing multiple tasks to multiple workers "**Threads**" but you can't run your application in the background.

**How to make your application work in the background?**

Google introduced some background limitations in Android Oreo. so to keep your application alive you need

1. **`foreground service by showing an ongoing notification.`**

**1. The way you should implement service is like**

```
public class YourService extends Service {

private static final int NOTIF_ID = 1;
private static final String NOTIF_CHANNEL_ID = "Channel_Id";

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){

    // do your jobs here

    startForeground();
    
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

private void startForeground() {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);

    startForeground(NOTIF_ID, new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, 
            NOTIF_CHANNEL_ID) // don't forget create a notification channel first
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText("Service is running background")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build());         
   }
}
```

**2. Also you need to start the service**

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        startService(new Intent(this, YourService.class));
    }
}
```

**3. Add your service in the "application" tag of your AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<service android:name=".YourService"/>
```

**4. And also this permission request in the "manifest" tag (if API level 28 or higher)**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
```

In this way, you can keep your service in the background. I suggest you read articles and see GitHub repositories, and also practice practice practice a lot to be good at Android :)

Comment: @KaitoKid your welcome mate, if you like the answer please learn how to upvote the answer and how to make the question "Answered" :D